# Counterexample needed that shows this family of graphs are not 3-color-able (vertex coloring)

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a graph such that $G$ is the disjoint union of $l$ circles such that each circle has a number of vertices which divides with 3. That is $G=\bigcup_{i \in \left[ l \right]}C_{3k_i}$. Denote $\Sigma_{i \in \left[ l \right]}k_i=k$ (note, $G$ has $3k$ vertices).

And  let $G_\Delta$ be a graph over the same $3k$ vertices such that $G_\Delta$ is composed of $k$ disjoint triangles ($G$ and $G_\Delta$ may or may not have shared edges).

Find such a $G$ and $G_\Delta$ such that $G \cup G_\Delta$ is not 3-color-able.

Note: In the case where $l=1$, that is $G=C_{3k}$, then the resulting graph **is** 3-color-able.
The same is true if $k_i = 1$ for every $i$. That is, if all circles are triangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a relatively simple example. Don't know why it took me so long to find it. Consider this graph:[image]

Each distinct shape denotes a triangle (for example all circular vertices).